# how to hide WKInterfaceButton in watchkit

Tags: watchkit, wkinterfacebutton

Does anyone know how I can programmatically hide a WKInterfaceButton in watchkit?

There doesn't seem to be a setHidden interface like a uibutton.

Comment: buttons do have a `setHidden`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mp states, wkinterfacebutton's have a setHidden method for setting the method to true or false.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: Thanks, Erik.  I will ask as a question.

Comment: sorry, that was an automated comment not me. it also seems it was invalid.